# Method chaning in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I create method chaining functionality similar to `jQuery` in `JavaScript`. For eg. I have a main function where I can add different methods to it like add, subtract, multiply, divide, while main function taking one param.

`Main(5).add(3).subtract(2).multiply(4).divide(6)`

or

`Main(10).subtract(5).add(5).divide(6)`

It can be anything.

I was trying to put methods in an object in the return statement of the parent function, but it didn't work.

```
function main(a) {
    return {
        sum: function (b) {
            return a + b;
        },
        substract: function (c) {
            return a - c;
        },
    };
}
```

Please help

Comment: "it didn't work" is never a sufficiently detailed description of what happened when you tried.  It could have been something as simple as the difference in case between `Main` and `main`.  Please report the exact error messages, or expected vs actual incorrect behaviour.

Comment: You have to return an object with those member fns. So the result should be added as a member too. Then an extra member fn to get the result.

Comment: Have a look at builder pattern https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
function Main(a) {
    this.value = a;
}

Main.prototype.sum = function (a) {
    this.value += a;
    return this;
}

Main.prototype.subtract = function (a) {
    this.value -= a;
    return this;
}
```

Usage:

```
let var1 = new Main(5).sum(3).subtract(2); // var1.value = 6
```

Comment: @Wyck works fine for me, check usage

Answer (score 1):

You could return an object of functions and store the result. At the end return only the value by taking a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) function.

```js
function chain(value) {
    const methods = {
        add: v => {
            value += v;
            return methods;
        },
        substract: v => {
            value -= v;
            return methods;
        },
        get value() { return value; }
    }
    return methods;
}

console.log(chain(3).add(4).substract(5).value);
```

Comment: A tiny bit confusing that the parameter name is `value` and the getter is also named `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a local variable `n`, perform the math on it, and then `return this` from each method.

```js
function main (n = 0) {
  return {
    add: function(x) {
      n = n + x;
      return this;
    },
    subtract: function(x) {
      n = n - x;
      return this;
    },
    total: function () {
      return n;
    }
  };
}

const total = main(12)
  .add(2)
  .subtract(1)
  .total();
  
console.log(total);
```